# Data is stored in elasticsearch but not shown while access from kibana

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Django as a backend with Postgres database and Angular JS as a frontend. When we signup from frontend then the data stored in Elasticsearch. It is stored in Elasticsearch because counts show all signup data but it is not shown when I search in Kibana by using this command:

```
GET candidate/_search
```

Output in Kibana:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 16,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "candidate",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "705",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 705,
          "user" : {
            "id" : 7005,
            "first_name" : "brain",
            "last_name" : "martine",
            "email" : "brain@yopmail.com",
            "employer_nm" : "A-1 hospitality",
            "property_owner" : "25hours Hotel Company"
          },
```

Here, the total count is 16, but it only shows 10 previous data which I added through Postman.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please use the text editor to properly format your question.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch by default fetch only the top 10 results, you can use `size` param to get more documents. Below example would fetch 100 documents from your index, as there are currently 16, Hence it would fetch 16.

```
GET candidate/_search?size=100
```

More info on [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html)

[image]